# Is there a way to turn off git conflict resolution?

Tags: git

Is there a way to completely turn off git's attempts to resolve conflicts before feeding files into 3-way merge tool?

I mean those lines:

```
<<<<<<< Temporary merge branch 1
...
=======
...
>>>>>>> Temporary merge branch 2
```

It adds them and branch changes into the base file before feeding it into kdiff3, and the later one goes completely mad showing weird conflicts.

I would like to simply have the base revision untouched.

So far I've only found the option

```
merge.conflictstyle
```

but it seems to have no option to turn these lines off.

Is there any way except writing a preprocessor that would strip the lines?

**UPDATE**

I'll explain what I dislike here.

The problem is that when git launches kdiff3 the BASE revision contains lines like

```
X1
<<<<<<< Temporary merge branch 1
A
=======
B
>>>>>>> Temporary merge branch 2
X2
```

The LOCAL revision contains:

```
X1
A
X2
```

And the REMOTE revision contains:

```
X1
B
X2
```

where `X1` and `X2` are some common lines of code between 3 files.

Now, kdiff3 signals a conflict here.

If I grab the files, copy them to a separate folder and remove everything between `<` and `>`, kdiff3 merges files way better, sometimes automatically.

From what I can see at http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-gui/, it looks like it actually should not show the lines in the BASE revision. But it does. How do I fix it?

**Git config**

`git config -l` gives this:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
user.name=Pavel Gatilov
user.email=********
merge.tool=kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
diff.guitool=kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
difftool.kdiff3.cmd="C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
core.editor="C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor
core.autocrlf=false
credential.helper=!"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitCredentialWinStore/git-credential-winstore.exe"
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
core.safecrlf=true
remote.origin.url=********
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=887x427+175+175 171 192
branch.8480-il.remote=origin
branch.8480-il.merge=refs/heads/8480-il
branch.branch-9354.remote=origin
branch.branch-9354.merge=refs/heads/branch-9354
```

**Versions**

I use:

```
Tool             Version
------------------------
msysgit          1.8.1.msysgit.1
Git Extensions   2.44
kdiff3           0.9.97
```

The issue exists both when I run merge via Git Extensions and via `git mergetool`

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried configuring kdiff3 preprocessor command to remove the unwanted parts of files, but it seems to work on a per-line basis, so it can't fix the issue.

I could write a preprocessor-wrapper, but I don't want to do that yet.

Comment: I never had problems with git in combination with kdiff3 and I didn't change any settings related to this. So I wonder what you exactly mean when you say that kdiff "goes completely mad showing weird conflicts".

Comment: It shouldn't.  What does your merge tool configuration look like?

Comment: It looks to me as if your BASE revision might actually have those lines in it, which it would get if the file had had an earlier merge conflict and someone 'git add'ed it without resolving anything.

Comment: @jthill I've checked your suggestion, it's not the case. The base revision is OK (I got it with the help of git merge-base).

Comment: @EdwardThomson Please, review the updated question

Comment: @jthill: I have had the issue you describe before, but today have exactly the same as described by PavelGatilov - the "real" base revision does NOT have any garbage, but the file that git feeds to the merge tool does... This is only happening on a specific commit, interestingly - previous merge conflict resolutions in the same repo went fine, but on this commit all the conflicted files are being garbled in this way when fed to the merge tool. Will be interesting to see if it happens again, or whether the issue is related to this specific merge in some way...

Comment: @Tao In my experience, this problem usually occurs if 3 or more branches are involved into cross-merges and 2 revisions from one branch are merged along different paths into another branch. For example, for 3 branches A, B, C you merge revision A1 into B, then later A2 into C, and finally C into B. In some cases both git and hg treat this as if the changes from A2 conflict with changes from A1. And both do strange things trying to resolve this. Unfortunately, I cannot make a simple repro...

Comment: I've had this a couple times, this particular one seems to be caused by a situation similar to your last comment and what appears to be different (manual) indentation in merge conflict resolution in the branches.

Comment: @Stijn: if so, wont `difftool.kdiff3.cmd="C:/Program Files (x86)/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"'` solve his issue?

Comment: @MTZ4 $BASE contains these merge markers already.

Answer (score 7):

You can set flags in the [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to configure gits behavior, to turn of git conflict resolution, we can use the [`merge=union`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_built_in_merge_drivers) flag to do this.

Example .gitattributes

```
* merge=union
```

Instead of specifying that all files have no merge option, we can also do this for a selective amount of files, for example:

```
*.java merge=union
src/generated/* merge=union
```

These lines tune the merge option for java files, and all files in the src/generated folder.

Comment: I won't be able to verify until this happens again, but I'll assume it's correct and award the bounty.

Comment: Yeah, the difficult part with this issue is that it turns out to be quite rare and hard to reproduce in an artificial repo. The solution looks promising, will check it if I have an opportunity.

Comment: I just had it occur again and your solution seems to work. The merge markers still appear in $BASE, but they no longer cause issues in $MERGED.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a case of setting up the config variable `mergetool.<tool>.cmd` to that you don't have the initial/default merge at all.

The `git merge-tool` is used *after* the merge has happened (so says the manual)

Comment: I've added the configuration. It doesn't seem to have `mergetool.kdiff3.cmd` specified.